# How can I set (or ignore) DTD properties with Powershell?

Tags: error-handling, powershell-2.0, dtd

I've got a powershell script that converts HTML documents to Word, RTF, Text and Word 2010 (.docx). A number of documents are erroring out with the following:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Word encountered an error processing the XML file Viewing_Customer_Payments.htm
DTD is prohibited.
Location:  Line: 2, Column: 9"
At C:\blah\blah\blah\blah\blah.PS1:95 char:36
+     $opendoc = $word.documents.open <<<< ($docs.FullName)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

I've been hunting for DTD Powershell info for a while, and while there's [plenty of documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.prohibitdtd.aspx) on setting the value to allow/disallow in C#, C++, VB, but precious little for Powershell. The [one page with potentially useful information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.prohibitdtd%28v=vs.80%29) loads with errors and won't display the powershell sample code; I suspect that's a function of not having the latest-greatest IE rolled out yet.

So in a perfect world, I'd like to include a line that would either allow DTD or ignore the prohibition in my script. I have no idea how to do that or even if there's something out there via powershell.

In case it matters, the SUCCESSFUL file conversions have this header:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">`

The documents ERRORING out use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wasn't able to ignore DTD using @GaussianBlur's suggestion, that solution did uncover some oddities in the metadata.

I noticed that anything with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` errored out, while files without that line in the HTML converted without incident.

A simple global replace/remove in all my HTML files solved that propblem quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Did some digging. One potential I saw [here](http://ditanauts.org/2012/02/01/reporting-on-your-dita-repository-with-powershell/), was to write a function that ignores the DTD. The idea should work for you as well.

```
Function Get-XML ($filePath) {
$fileContent = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$fileContent.XmlResolver = $null
Try {
    $fileContent.Load($filePath)
    }
Catch [system.exception] {
    write-host "Could not open file $filePath"
}
$fileContent
```

}

Comment: Looks exactly like it'll do the trick...once I figure out how to integrate it... :)  Especially thrilled about the link; we're converting all these docs so we can DITA-ize them. I know where I'm going to be spending a lot of 'net time. :)

Answer (score 0):

For what I needed, I got this working using just one line from Gaussian Blur's answer

I already had this:
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML

I just added this:
$xml.XmlResolver = $null

This successfully ignores the DTD